# For a two-stage cluster deployed in Apache IoTDB, why the confignode of the second server cannot be started and added to the seed confignode?

Tags: startup, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I have a two-stage cluster deployed using Apache IoTDB. The first server has been started successfully, but the second server cannot be started successfully. The confignode of the first server has been started and the datanode has not been started yet. However, according to the official guide, I need to start the seed confignode first, and then add new confignodes, so I experienced this abnormal situation.I checked some common reason that may caused this problem, but found nothing. The ip address (10710) of the second server is not occupied by any process. The firewall should also already been stopped. I also already upgrade IoTDB Version to 1.3.0, but this problem still happened. Can anyone suggest possible reason for this problem, or how can I do the troubleshooting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to unzip an installation package with default configuration (as the second server itself becomes a new cluster) and try to start the ConfigNode of Apache IoTDB again. If it still cannot be started, then there should be a problem with the server itself. If it can be started, then there may be a problem with the environment settings. You can also check if the configuration settings of DataNode, especially the rpc ip settings, and see if you got that wrong. This may also cause the problem you encountered.